# Global.asax + Unknown error caught in Application_Error

Tags: asp.net, exception

When I boot up my program, I will immediately get a 'File does not exist' error logged inside my log file. I then tried to create a clean web form without any master page but still receiving this error, odd thing but probably good for me is it does not perform a redirection like the usual exceptions caught. From the logged file, I couldn't tell anything from the message. Anyone has a clue? Thanks.

```
 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs       
            Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            log.Error(objErr.Message, objErr);
            Response.Redirect("~/error.aspx");
        }

ERROR 11 GoogleMap_AutoFill_with_Obtain_LatLong.Global - File does not exist.
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): File does not exist.
   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String overrideVirtualPath)
   at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Looks like a javascript is call the Google Map `Lat Long Globe` to auto fill some address, and is not corrected setup and call local for this that looks like a file.